# Borrow Checker: How to immutably borrow from an immutable member of a mutable struct?

Tags: rust

In this example: https://godbolt.org/z/qjnq31zsW

```
pub struct Parser<'a>  {
    pub tokens: &'a Vec<&'a str>,
    pub counter: usize
}



pub fn advance<'a>(p: &'a mut Parser) -> &'a str {
    p.counter += 1;
    p.tokens[p.counter-1]
}

pub fn build_expression<'a>(p: &'a mut Parser) -> Vec<&'a str>{

    let there = advance(p);
    let once = advance(p);
    let was = advance(p);

    vec![there, once, was]

}


fn main(){
    
    let sentence = "there once was a lady who swallowed a fly".to_string();
    
    let words = vec![ &sentence[0..5],
                      &sentence[6..10],
                      &sentence[11..14],
                      &sentence[15..16],
                      &sentence[17..21],
                      &sentence[22..25],
                      &sentence[26..35],
                      &sentence[36..37],
                      &sentence[38..41],
    ];
    
    println!("{:?}", words);


    let mut p = Parser{tokens:&words, counter:0};
    let expr = build_expression(&mut p);

    println!("{:?}", expr);

}
```

I have a struct that contains some immutable data (the list of words/tokens), as well as some mutable data (a counter to the current word).

How can I convince the borrow checker to let me mutate the counter while another part of the code borrows a word/token

Comment: Rust does not recognize "partial" mutable / immutable distinction. A struct is either all immutable or all mutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can communicate to the compiler that your references do not derive from the `Parser`, `p`, but rather from what it references. You do this by linking the return value `&'a str` to `&mut Parser<'a>` rather than `&'a mut Parser`:

```
pub fn advance<'a>(p: &mut Parser<'a>) -> &'a str {
    p.counter += 1;
    p.tokens[p.counter-1]
}

pub fn build_expression<'a>(p: &mut Parser<'a>) -> Vec<&'a str>{
    let there = advance(p);
    let once = advance(p);
    let was = advance(p);

    vec![there, once, was]
}
```

See it working on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=58fe41be1d0c971bdff1cfbf0dbffe9e).

Since the references are backed by a different lifetime, you safely disconnect those references from the parser itself so that it is not bound by them and allows you to mutate it.